# Using a Vlookup to change a column letter inside a Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using a google sheets query expression that extracts data from a table where the column headers include a price list and then the number of products used by client. Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with:

[Sample Tables and Query](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VqUCf8SCHZjFZJM60h-AQkSGUxCF4nxBl9DYjL53ml8/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to be able to type in the client's name into a cell that would trigger a vlookup that changes the column letter in the query. Don't know if that's possible.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with your shape of table, it's easier to use hlookup instead of vlookup (works the same way but on rows not columns).

```
=query({A3:E19},"Select Col1, Col2, Col"&hlookup(H1,{C3:E3;C1:E1},2,false))
```

[image]

You can also use MATCH formula to return number of column that you want to display in query.

Here is working solution
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtFdlFi2iMnKlWf2NI8BtULeAyMpEHsiRTfR36TqV6M/copy

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I was able to replicate and adapt it to my process. One thing I was unable to figure out was how to add a where clause to the formula that included the hlookup  (to show only rows with values for a client), but by using an additional query on the query, I got the output I needed.

Comment: You exit query and get back to it using "query content"&some formula&"query content continues".  . So here you should make like this: =query({A3:E19},"Select Col1, Col2, Col"&hlookup(H1,{C3:E3;C1:E1},2,false)&" where Col1 is not null") - if you like my answers, please click up arrow to give me points.

Comment: Thanks for the further work. I like being able to add to the query after the lookup, however, the column that needs to be filtered is the same as the hlookup column. Is it possible to filter on that column?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Do you mean that you want for example "Suzy" column twice?

Comment: I'm hoping to get only the rows where there is a value under the customer name. So for Suzy, I would only see Widget 2.

Comment: If you want to eliminate rows with no data for certain column, you should add clause: "where Col3 is not null" - if you mean Column 3. In this case you have to repeat hlookup that returns this column number: =query({A3:E19},"Select Col1, Col2, Col"&hlookup(H1,{C3:E3;C1:E1},2,false)&" where Col"&hlookup(H1,{C3:E3;C1:E1},2,false)&" is not null")

Comment: That works! I just couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks again for helping with this question.

Comment: Hi, If you appreciate my answers, please mark them with arrow up as useful. This is how we do on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Hi Krzysztof - I've voted up each time, but since I'm a first time questioner, they say my vote is recorded but not counted. I hope others who have had more time on the site find this exchange useful and vote it up some more.